# Java - Variable Scope

Tags: java

I'm brand new to java and I have a super n00bish question. (I do have some general programming knowledge). I'm trying to access the variable "item" to no avail. Can someone spot why?

```
    public void start() 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter saleman's name: ");
        String name = input.next();

       int exit = 0;
       do 
       {
           System.out.println("Enter item number: ");
           String item = input.next();
           if (ValidateItem(item) == true)
           {
               if (Integer.parseInt(item) <=4 && Integer.parseInt(item) >=1)\
               {
                   exit = 1;
               }
               else 
                   System.out.println("Enter an item number between 1 and 4");
           }

           if (ValidateItem(item) == false)
           {
                System.out.println("Enter an item number between 1 and 4");
           }

       } while (exit == 0);

       int exitQuan = 0;
       do 
       {
           System.out.println("Enter quantity (1-99): ");
           String quant = input.next();
           if (ValidateItem(quant) == true)
           {
                exitQuan = 1;
           }
           else 
               System.out.println("Enter a quantity between 1 and 99");
       } 
       while (exitQuan == 0);

       if (item == 1) 
       {
           pay = 239.99;
       }
```

The last IF STATEMENT is where I'm lacking scope. 
Thanks.

Comment: Declare the variable in a greater scope. Right now its scope is the first `do-while` block.

Comment: Please format your code according to the Java coding conventions.

Comment: You seriously need to learn, how to format code... Also, don't post like half a method.

Comment: I hate to jump on the bandwagon here, but indenting your code properly would make this obvious.

Comment: In Java the variable's scope is the class or function that it is defined in. In this case, `item` only exists in your `do-while` loop. To use it farther down, declare `item` before the `do-while`, like you do with `exit`.

Comment: Also, `item` is a `String`, you cannot compare it to an `int`.

Comment: Another note, you are writing `if(x == true)`. This is pointless. Write `if(x)` or `if(!x)`.

Answer (score 4):

Variable scope only extends to the smallest pair of braces that surround the declaration. For instance:

```
//this could be a method body, an if statement, a loop, whatever
{
    int x;
} //x passes out of scope here
```

Therefore, when you declare `item` inside of a `do-while` loop, its scope ends once you exit the loop. To fix this, declare `item` above the loop like this:

```
String item = null; //initialize to null to avoid warning about using an un-initialized variable

do {
    System.out.println("Enter item number: ");
    item = input.next();

    //rest of loop...

} while (exit == 0);
```

This way `item` will be available until the method returns.

Answer (score 1):

Declare variable Item outside the do-while loop.

```
int exit = 0;
String item = null;
    do {
    System.out.println("Enter item number: ");
    itm = input.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared item in the first `do-while` loop, you can't use it in the second, because when the control flow exists from the first loop, `item` goes out of scope.

Also, as others suggested, proper intentation would have helped you a lot ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The item variable is declared in the first do while loop
Hence you can access it inside the do while loop
To access the item in the scope of the function, you should declare it before the do while loop, so that it can be accessed in the if(item==1) statement

Answer (score 0):

```
int exit = 0;
String item = null;
do {
System.out.println("Enter item number: ");
item = input.next();
if (ValidateItem(item) == true){
    if (Integer.parseInt(item) <=4 && Integer.parseInt(item) >=1){
        exit = 1;}
else System.out.println("Enter an item number between 1 and 4");
}
if (ValidateItem(item) == false){
    System.out.println("Enter an item number between 1 and 4");}
} while (exit == 0);

int exitQuan = 0;
do {
 System.out.println("Enter quantity (1-99): ");
 String quant = input.next();
 if (ValidateItem(quant) == true){
            exitQuan = 1;}
    else System.out.println("Enter a quantity between 1 and 99");
} while (exitQuan == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `item` has scope to the `do while` loop it is defined in.

```
int exit = 0;
String item = null; // <-- Add this
```

then change your loop

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter item number: ");
    item = input.next(); // <-- Defined outside this scope now.
    if (ValidateItem(item) == true) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(item) <= 4 && Integer.parseInt(item) >= 1) {
            exit = 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter an item number between 1 and 4");
        }
    } else { // <-- just use else
        // if (ValidateItem(item) == false) {
        System.out.println("Enter an item number between 1 and 4");
    }
} while (exit == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java the variables are local (declared inside a method or inside a constructor) or instance variable (declared inside a class but outside of method). In your case item lives only in the first do while, you can't access it outside the loop. Make item declaration outside the do-while (global variable). I recommend using methods in Java (we are in OOP not in procedural paradigma).
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One won't face any problem if he knows the basic java scope rules

1- The scope of a parameter declaration is the body of the method in which the declaration appears

2- The scope of a local-variable declaration is from the point at which the declaration appears to the end of that block

3- The scope of a local-variable declaration that appears in the initialization section of a for statement's header is the body of the for statement and other expressions in the header

4- A method or field's scope is the entire body of the class

Be careful about declaring local variables which have the same name as the class instance variables since it would shadow the instance variable and makes confusion about the scope of the variables and program readability