# Why can you have a duplicate variable name in java for a variable outside of a method?

Tags: java

I am learning Java and I understand that you cannot name a variable declared within an inner scope the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope as shown below

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 10;
        if (x == 10){
            int x = 10;
        }           
    }   
}
```

However, I noticed that the following is not illegal

```
public class Practice {
    int x = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 10;
        if (x == 10) {
        }           
    }   
}
```

Is this not a variable that is declared twice??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Variable Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147813/java-variable-scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this not a variable that is declared twice??

No, it is not. Because they both are in different scope. `x` outside of `main` function has **class level scope** while `x` inside of `main` has **method/function level scope**.

**It is legal for 2 variables in different scope to have same name.**

Please DO read [§6.3. Scope of a Declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) from JLS. Below are few of the statement from that section.

> The scope of a declaration is the region of the program within which
>   the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a
>   simple name, provided it is visible (§6.4.1).
>
> A declaration is said to be in scope at a particular point in a
>   program if and only if the declaration's scope includes that point.
>
> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the
>   rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its
>   own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in
>   the local variable declaration statement.

There are lot of concepts related to scope like **shadowing**, so do read [§6.4. Shadowing and Obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4).

**JLS is the best place to learn what is allowed and what is not allowed in Java.** Feel free to read sections there.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case when `x` is declared outside the method, it is an instance variable of the class `Practice`. Within the method, scope of `x`(declared inside `main`) is limited to the `main` method.

In the first case when you declare `x` within the method, you cannot declare it inside `if` because it is already declared in the scope of the method outside `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippets shows the variables are in method's scope. So two variable are belonging to same method which is not allowed.

But in the second example one variable is on instance level and the other one in method's scope, so there is no duplicate. In the second example if you want to access the instance variable, you have to do it using this.x.

Check more on scope and lifetime of variables here

http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/scope-and-lifetime-of-variables

Answer (score 0):

> Why can you have a duplicate variable name in java for a variable outside of a method?

It is not illegal because it is allowed by the Java Language Specification.  (Yes ... circular explanation)

As with all such questions, we cannot tell you for sure *why* it is allowed, because the Java language was designed behind closed doors.  However, a couple of possible reasons are:

- Java was originally designed to be "palatable" to C and C++ programmers, and this is a case where doing it differently (banning shadowing) would have caused objections.
- A lot of people actually like it that they don't have to think of different names for variables; e.g.

  ```
   public class Foo {
       private Bar bar;

       public Foo() {
          Bar bar = new Bar();
          this.bar = bar;
       }
   }
  ```

Admittedly, there is a downside.  Sometimes, people *mistakenly* declare local variables that shadow instance (or static) variables.  Particularly newbies :-)

---

> Is this not a variable that is declared twice??

No.  It is actually two >>distinct<< variables.  Both exist.  Within the method, the local declaration of `x` *shadows* the instance declaration of `x`.  But you can still refer to the latter as `this.x`.