# Discrepancy in "rules" with variables with same name

Tags: java, variables

Unlike in C, in Java, declaring a **variable of the same name** in a smaller scope is illegal as it can be a source of programming errors right?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        int n;

        {
          String n; //illegal in Java as they have same name. 
        }
}
```

But why does this rule not apply when creating constructors? (is this just some design flaw?)

```
class FirstTime
{
  private int instanceField;

  public FirstTime(int arg)
  {
    int instanceField=arg; //Why is this legal in Java? Isn't this the same concept like the above code
  }

}
```

Edit: This link [Why can you have a duplicate variable name in java for a variable outside of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35248937/13748491) is similar but in the duplicate question, the variables were of "totally different" scope, like one is in `main` method and one is outside. But in my example, both are in the class `FirstName` aren't they?

Comment: The latter can be distinguished by `this.instanceField` and `instanceField`, but the former is not.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter In the duplicate question, the variables were of "totally different" scope, like one is in `main` method and one is outside. But in my example, both are in the class `FirstName` aren't they?

Comment: @saka1029  The keyword `this` refers to the object so I guess you could differentiate the 2 `instanceField`s but I  feel like why it doesn't answer why the 2nd code is "legal"

Comment: @HelloWorld *"In my example, both are in the class FirstName aren't they?"* --- No, the first is an *instance variable*, same as in the duplicate, and the second is a *local variable* inside a constructor/method, also same as in the duplicate, so the duplicate is truly the same as you example. --- By contrast, the your `main` method, both a local variables.

Comment: As for **why**, the answer is that *instance variables* can be inherited from super classes, which might be from a third party, which means an update of such a super class might add a new *instance variable* that happens to end up clashing with variables defined by you in the subclass. Such name clashing is allowed, to prevent the need to force you to change the code, since the change to the super class might otherwise be considered backwards compatible.

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on my question building and check for duplicates next time