# Compiler can't find variable in method with for,if/else return statement

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, methods

I have a method, which keeps giving me compilation errors. At first I had a return statement for the if and else statements. I couldn't get it to work with 2 return statements, so I changed it into what I have now.

The error message now says that it can't find variable 'x'. I put the return statement inside the previous set of {}, and that still never worked. So I'm not sure if I have to completely redesign my method, or if this is a simple fix.

```
public static boolean equalN(int [] holdN){
    for(int i=0;i<=holdN.length;i++){
        int k=1;
        boolean x;
        if(holdN[i]==holdN[k]){
            k++;
            x=true;
        }
        else{
            x=false;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: `x` is defined inside the for loop and is out of scope when you try to return it.

Comment: Why are you trying to redefine the variable each time over the loop?

Comment: Are you aware that array indexes start at 0?  The first element is `holdN[0]` and the last is `holdN[holdN.length-1]`.  The way you've written it, (1) you're comparing every element of the array to the _second_ element, which is probably harmless, and (2) the last time through the loop will check `holdN[i]` where `i == holdN.length`, and since this is _past_ the last element of the array, you'll get an exception because there is no array element with that index.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot return `x` at the end of the method is that it is defined inside the loop, so its scope ends before you want to return it.

The same applies to variable `k`; good news is that you do not need either one of them.

> At first I had a return statement for the if and else statements.

You can make it work with two `return` statements:

- First `return` statement should be inside the `if`: once you detect the item that your loop is looking for, return `true`
- Second `return` statement is at the end of the method, after the end of the loop. The only way to reach that point is for the loop to never return from the middle, which means that no item has been found. Hence, you return `false`.

Comment: This might be backwards... it's not well explained what she's trying to do, but I'm guessing the method is supposed to return `true` if all elements in the array are equal.  Based on that, she'll need to return `false` inside the loop if she detects an element that isn't equal to the first one, and `true` at the end of the loop if no non-matching element is found.

Answer (score 0):

Variable scoping is your problem here:

```
for(int i=0;i<=holdN.length;i++){
    ...
    boolean x;
    // x exists and is valid here
    ...
}

// but x doesn't exist here

return x; // this will fail compilation
```

}

**To solve your compilation problem, you should move the declaration of x above the for loop.**

```
boolean x;
for(int i=0;i<=holdN.length;i++){
    ...
}
return x;
```

}

For further explanation, see [this SO question about variable scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147813/java-variable-scope).