# Passing user input between cases in switch java

Tags: java

I have a small problem with this code. I added lecturer in *case 1* and I trying to add books to this lecturer in *case 3*. problem is that it seems that *case 3* doesn't recognize the created lecturer.

Is there any way to pass this value.

The solution is probably very simple but at this hour I just can not get it...

```
public class Menu {
static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
LectureList lec = new LectureList(100);

BookList bl = new BookList(0);
public Menu(){

}

public int mainMenu(){
    int option = 0;

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("                    Lecturer Menue                       ");
    System.out.println("*********************************************************");
    System.out.println("1) Add Lecturer");
    System.out.println("2) Find Lecturer by ID");
    System.out.println("3) Add book to Lecturer BookList");
    System.out.println("4) Remove book from Lecturer BookList ");
    System.out.println("5) Search for a book using the ISBN number");
    System.out.println("6) Calculate the yearly book payment");
    System.out.println("7) Output all of the book details in the system to a file");
    System.out.println("8) Exit");
    boolean selected = false;

    while (selected == false)
    {


        try 
        {
            option = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            if 
                ((option == 8)){

                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);}


            else if 
            ((option <= 0) || (option > 8))
                System.out.println("Sorry but you have to choose an option between 1 and 8");
            else
                selected = true;



        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry you did not enter a valid option");

            in.next();
        }       

    }

    return option;

}
public void menuSwitch(){
    boolean finish = false;
    if (finish == false){
        int option = mainMenu();

        switch (option){

        case 1: 
            String LecName = " ";

            System.out.println("Please enter Lecturer's  name");
            LecName = in.nextLine();
            Lecturer l = new Lecturer(LecName);


            lec.add(l);

            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            String name = "";
            Double price = 00.00 ;
            String isbn ="";
            String author = "";

            System.out.println("Please enter Book title ");
            name = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter Book's price ");
            price = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter Book's isbn number ");     
            isbn = in.next();       
            System.out.println("Please enter book author's name");
            author = in.next();
            Book b = new Book( name,  price,  isbn,  author);

            l.addBook(b);



            break;``
            default: 
            finish = true;
            break;
        }
        menuSwitch();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I need to Lecturer l = new Lecturer(LecName); add  l.addBook(b), but I get the message" The local variable l may not have been initialized"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147813/java-variable-scope

Answer (score 0):

Every `case` statement in your `switch` finishes with a `break;`, and the `default` case does as well.  In that case, for any pass through the `switch` statement, only a single `case` label will be executed.

If the first pass executes the first `case`, and the second pass executes the second `case`, the variables defined in the first case will no longer be around -- they will have fallen out of scope when the `switch` statements completes the first time.

Can you get a reference to your `Lecturer` from the `LectureList` collection?

In `case 1:` you can create it and put it in the collection;  in `case 3:` you can obtain it back from the collection and update it.